# Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?

Tags: clearcase

I've got to upload my changed files for code review, but I have the following issue:

I need to find all the files in my view that have changed since my last code review upload.  I thought I labeled all the files when I did the last review upload, but it appears that I didn't.

How do I find all clearcase elements in my current view that have a date newer than the date of my last upload?  There have been MANY check-ins since the last upload.

Comment: You should clarify whether you're using 'normal' or UCM clearcase.

Answer (score 6):

This is a [cleartool find](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) request with a time-based directive from the [query language](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm):

(See [Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rcss=faqtt_1Q09&uid=swg21124425))

```
cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
```

That will list *elements* (instead of *versions*, which would display many checkins versions for every file)

This should work for snapshot or dynamic views, UCM or not ("UCM" being for views attached to an UCM Stream).

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like it might work: I had trouble finding the Query Language documentation.

Comment: @Luciano: yes, and I find the list of find examples more useful that the query language page ;)

Comment: @VonC I believe it just list the files created since the specified date, but the question asks for the files modified since the date.

Comment: @neves true, that was the best approximation I found at the time.

Answer (score 5):

You could look for all versions in your view that are older than a date:

```
ct find -all -type f -version "{created_since(11-apr-2013) && brtype(branch_name)}" -print
```

Will find all files and avoid directories.