# clearcase: show recently changed files

Tags: clearcase

Is there a clearcase command to show me say all the files and the respective committers/activities that have changed in the last X hours/days? Something similar to svn/git/hg log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, because ClearCase is [file-centric, not repository centric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771).

So you can make your query for a component or a Stream (list of components+baselines).

For instance, to list all activities for a given stream, you can type (using the [`fmt` option of `lsact`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm)):

```
cleartool lsact -fmt "%n %d" -in aStream@\aPVob -user auser
```

But then, you need to filter on the date to get only the activities you want, and you can the describe each activities in order to get their changeset.

---

For the files, you can use a find query similar to "[Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676263/find-files-in-clearcase-view-newer-than-a-specific-date/7676484#7676484)":

```
 cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -print
 cleartool find <vobtag> -element "{created_since(target-data-time)}" -exec "cleartool desc -fmt \"%n %u %[activity]p\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Using [`-fmt` options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), you can display the user for that version, and the activity whose change set contains the specified version.

Comment: Well, I guess I´ll accept your answer. It just fits well into the general impression I got about Clearcase. It all sounds pretty useless to me, unless your project has less than 3 files.. But that´s not your fault :)

Comment: @zedoo I completely agree with your general impression. ClearCase doesn't scale well.