# Get all versions from a specific time - ClearCase UCM

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

We are using ClearCase UCM, and someone asked me if there is a way to get all of the versions from a specific time.

Example:  Work is being done on a development stream.  Someone broke the build, but the previous baseline is too far back and we would lose too much work.  They would like to get the  versions of every file that was there from last Thursday at 11:00am.

Is this possible, even if it hasn't been baselined at that specific time?
Is there a way to revert back to that specific time?

(I searched for a similar topic, but most of them were "versions created since...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "created_since" is about find queries similar to "[Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676263/find-files-in-clearcase-view-newer-than-a-specific-date/7676484#7676484)".

But in your case, it is easier to define a dynamic view, with a specific config spec **[time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635282/6309)**:

```
element /myPath/... .../StreamName/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/{!created_since(16-Sep-2009)}
element /myPath/... /main/LATEST
```

So it would be a plain base-ClearCase dynamic view (easier to test when fiddling with the config spec: no files to load like in a snapshot view).
The fact that those files are currently managed by an UCM view in an UCM component doesn't preclude using base-ClearCase views.

The idea is to look for the versions at the right date:

- first in the `StreamName` branch (if those files have been checked-out)
- if not, in `main` branch

From there, if you want to "revert" to that content in your current UCM view, the easiest way to to re-import everything with a **[clearfsimport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138321/how-can-i-use-clearcase-to-add-to-source-control-recursively/144310#144310)** (`-rmname` to achieve the exact same content).
Create an UCM activity dedicated to that "re-import" in order to register all impacted files.

Comment: Note: the syntax mentioned here is one alternative (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1578508/6309). The other (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634509/clearcase-loading-older-version-of-a-specific-directory) is more like: `element /aVob/myComponent/mySubDirectory/... .../STREAM_NAME/LATEST -time dd-Month-yyyy`.