# How to find files or elements which are not modified after a paticular version in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase

How to find files or elements which are not modified after a paticular version in ClearCase?
Like I want to find all the elements which were not modified after version 1(no versions after version 1).

Or Can we find all the elements which are not modified after a particular date in ClearCase?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in "[Find files in Clearcase view newer than a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676263/find-files-in-clearcase-view-newer-than-a-specific-date)", you can find files newer (since then), not before.

That means you would need to:

- find all files
- find those with version *post* a certain date
- deduce the resulting group of files by removing the second set from the first.

Regarding version, you can try and find all files without version 2, for instance:

```
cleartool find . -version 'version(.../bugs/2)' -print
```

But remember, a version can be deleted, and a file would still have a version 3, 4... so it is not a guarantee.